# How would I create a answered answer vs correct answer function in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

`clicker-results` consumes a list of ClickerResponse lists called `answers`.
The function produces the clicker grade as a percentage based on the answers given. Clicker grades are determined as follows.

• If the student’s answer matches the correct answer, the student receives 2 points

• If the student’s answer does not match the correct answer, the student receives 1 point

• If the student did not provide an answer 'NA, the student receives 0 points

What I have so far.

```
(define (clicker-results grades)
   (lambda (s count)
     (+ count
        (cond
          [(empty? grades) 0]
          [(equal? (first (first grades)) (first (rest (first grades)))) 2]
          [(not (equal? (first (first grades)) (first (rest (first grades))))) 1]
        [else 0]))))
```

Although I am not getting an output.

Examples:

```
(clicker-results (list (list 'a 'a))) ⇒ 100
(clicker-results (list (list 'a 'a) (list 'NA 'b) 
(list 'c 'b) (list 'd 'e))) ⇒ 50
```

Comment: use set! or define (f answers count)

Comment: I am not allowed to use set!. And how would I locally define define (f answers count)

Comment: When answers empty return count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're still struggling with recursion :( that `lambda` inside doesn't have anything, at all to do with a correct answer. Have you taken a look at the template, of how to build a recursive solution?

And where are you calling the recursion? and how are you converting the answer from points to percentage?

This is more like it, and notice that you have to handle the `'NA` case explicitly, and it's better to have a separate helper procedure for calculating the percentage:

```
(define clicker-results
  (lambda (answers)
    (* 100.0 (/ (clicker-points answers) (* 2 (length answers))))))

(define clicker-points
  (lambda (answers)
    (cond [(empty? answers) 0]
          [(equal? (first (first answers)) 'NA)
           (clicker-points (rest answers))]
          [(equal? (first (first answers)) (first (rest (first answers))))
           (+ 2 (clicker-points (rest answers)))]
          [else (+ 1 (clicker-points (rest answers)))])))
```

The results would be:

```
(clicker-results (list (list 'a 'a)))
=> 100
(clicker-results (list (list 'a 'a) (list 'NA 'b) (list 'c 'b) (list 'd 'e)))
=> 50
```

Comment: Thank you Oscar, yes I was confused. So if i wanted to implement lambda could I still go about it the same way?

Comment: You're _already_ using a `lambda`. `clicker-results ` _is_ a `lambda`, the same as any other procedure. I rewrote my answer to make it more explicit, that there was a `lambda` there, all along.

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do with the `(lambda (s count)` part, anyway? there's no way that will work with the sample examples you posted, unless I'm mistaken, you're misunderstanding the problem requirements. It's not about writing a `lambda` there for the heck of it, is about what you are trying to do with it, and why.

Comment: So to convert the points to a percentage I should use a helper function? And to calculate the percentage wouldn't I need to divide the correct points by the number of questions and multiply by 100?

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry I had missed the part of the percentages.